# Spoon is not supported on this hosttype : MINGW64_NT-6.1

Tags: java, mingw, pentaho, mingw-w64, pentaho-spoon

I'm trying to open entaho Spoon on a Windows 7 machine, but it's not openning.
When I run SpoonDebug, the SpoonDebug.txt brings me this error:

Spoon is not supported on this hosttype : MINGW64_NT-6.1

What should I do?
when I run Git Bash, MINGW64_NT is the name on the header of the program.

Comment: Have you tried starting it from the normal Windows CMD, and not from MINGW bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is you are trying to run spoon.sh on windows 7 using cygwin or any of shell emulator for windows.
This output as you wrote:

```
MINGW64_NT-6.1
```

Is just output from [sh file](https://code.google.com/p/pentaho-cat/source/browse/trunk/pentaho-cat/New+Folder/spoon.sh?r=8#113) - output of

```
uname -s
```

What actually just happens - spoon.sh make attempt to guess the platform you are using and based on platform name - choose correct swt implementation. Since you are on win7 correct one should be with /win in path. 64 or 86 depending on your core. spoon.sh trying to guess only linux/osx based implementations and will not go to win swt folder.

So on win should run Spoon.bat for SpoonDebug.bat. spoon.sh only for unix/linux and seems will not guess the win swt even running in shell simulator that able to execute sh files.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are using the GitBash terminal to run the pentaho sh files (I know this is the best way we can probably simulate a linux envt on a windows system , even i do the same thing )

What you have to get rid of this validation is

Go to spoon.sh , You could see case statements for Linux, AIX etc..
starting with **case `uname -s` in** 
You basically need to add one condition for MINGW64_NT-6.1

You can even copy paste the linux settings as-is and replace the **Linux)**   with **MINGW64_NT-6.1)**. This is the tweak which is working for me over years now.